# Entanglement Entropy of Infinite Gapped Systems

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, quantum-entanglement

I have been using TeNPy's DMRG algorithm to understand some aspects of von Neumann entanglement entropy. Using infinite DMRG, I simulated various infinite gapped systems and computationally determined the entanglement entropy and entanglement spectrum. For the former, I got one number and for the latter I got a list of numbers. From this list, I was able to determine the list of singular values and from this I confirmed that the entanglement entropy obtained this way equals the single number the computer gave.

This seems to suggest that for infinite systems, entanglement entropy is cut independent. Is just a computer thing or is it really true that entanglement entropy of infinite systems is cut independent? Please let me know.

Comment: By "list of numbers" are you referring to the Schmidt values returned by the [entanglement_spectrum()](https://tenpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/tenpy.networks.mps.MPS.html#tenpy.networks.mps.MPS.entanglement_spectrum) function? If so I see no evidence that you're testing more than a single entanglement cut, so maybe you can clarify?

Comment: @Anyon Thank you for your comment. Actually, I get two lists of numbers, each list corresponding to one entanglement spectrum. I realized now that the two lists are outputted because two-site infinite DMRG has two bonds. Cutting one gives one list and cutting the other gives the other. Yes by list of numbers I am referring to the Schmidt values.